# Is there a way to expand selection to scope in CoffeeScript in Sublime Text?

Tags: scope, coffeescript, selection, sublimetext

Due to absence of curly braces in CoffeeScript it is sometimes hard to find out borders of scope of the functions, conditional statements, loops and else.

Is there a plugin or may be natively implemented way for expanding selection to scope in CoffeeScript files?
I find this feature very useful.

---

*No scope selection in CoffeeScript*

[image: CoffeeScript without scope selection]

*Scope selection in JavaScript*

[image: JavaScript with scope selection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ExpandRegion](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ExpandRegion) package does directly support coffeescript, but supports python, which is also indentation based. The "python expansion" will automatically applied to coffeescript, haskell, and yaml. Hence this would work as desired.

demo:

[image: Expand to Region]